# clicking on page title

Tags: php, wordpress, title

In the wordpress website I'm looking for something so that I can disable clicking titles in category posts.

Just want them to be a simple text not a link one

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to edit the page templates?

Answer (score 0):

In your wordpress tempplate file you should see something like

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php sprintf( __( 'Permanent Link to %s', 'theme-name' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

Simply remove the `<a>` surrounfing it.

You can also do this client site.

It's very easy if you have jQuery:

```
jQuery('.fancy').each(function(_,el){
  var el = jQuery(el);        
  el.text(el.find('a').text())
 })
```